# Procedure was expanded as instream procedure definition

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am a newbie to `mainframes` and `JCl`. I am getting the error:

> "Procedure was expanded as instream procedure definition"

this is my `JCL`.
I am getting the message `IEFC001I` . Somone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I can't see your JCL. Also, this "Procedure was expanded...." does not sound like an error. Is there any other message in the output?

Comment: That is not an error message (the I at the end of IEFC001I indicates that it is an information message). It is telling you that is has expanded a Instream-JCL-Procedure (see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jcl/jcl_procedures.htm).

Comment: Please include JCL and find the Error message (it may end E)

Comment: Messages which end in `I` are `Information` messages. These do not cause jobsteps to fail, but if a jobstep has failed, sometimes, in association with a non-`I` message, assist in problem-determination. Here it is just saying "I found a reference to a `PROC` (a `JCL` Procedure) and resolved the reference to the `PROC` with the `instream` PROC coded in the `JCL` rather than from a library (a `PROCLIB`)". You will get that message every time you use an instream procedure, whether the jobstep abends, fails, or completes with RC 0.

Comment: If your step is failing, we need to see all the messages and the JCL from file two of the spool output for your JOB. We also need to know what are the symptoms of the step failing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the title of this question should be renamed to **What means IEFC001I message "Procedure was expanded as instream procedure definition"**? Even though you seem to have forgotten to include your JCL (as per your "This in my JCL"), I don't think there is a need for including such JCL to be able, to answer your question.

When a JCL is submitted, the job that starts running may result in a message like so:

> Procedure was expanded as instream procedure definition

The message identifier related to that message is IEFC001I. Note the "I" at the end of this message, which stands for something like "Informational only" (instead of "E" for error, or "A" for Abend"). So this is not to be considered as an error.

What it is actually trying to say, is that your JCL contained the details of some "procedure", which in this case was added to the JCL itself (= instream). An alternative could have been that some JCL jobstep was executing a procedure, with a member that can be found in one of the typical libraries where lots of such procedures are located also, like DSN=SYS1.PROCLIB .

Note: as a variation to using "instream procedures", you may also want to use the "JCLLIB ORDER = ..." statement. That allows you to specify 1 or more DSNs in which you want you r JCL to go look for any proclib members you are using in your JCL. I often use that technique when I'm testing an updated procedure member (before actually installing it in the "official proclib DSNs", and which is used if you do not specify any such JCLLIB ORDER ...